# How to pass data to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

What I am trying to do is that the numbers to which my application sends messages to, are passed to the BraodcastReceiver...but so far either I am getting null or BroadcastReceiver just simply crashes..

here is my intent for BroadcastReceiver from CreateMessage class...

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("phN", phoneNo);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in BroadcastReceiver (SmsReceiver class) I am trying to catch intent like this..

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try{
    //receiveNumbers = intent.getExtras().get("phN").toString();
        String  receiveNumbers = intent.getStringExtra("phN");
        Toast.makeText(context, receiveNumbers, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.AEM_n"
      android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="2.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>    
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".new_menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SetEvent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.AEM_n.SETEVENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AddParticipants" />
            <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".CreateMessage" />
            <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DataBaseClass" />
            <activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".IntentReceiver"/>
            <activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            />
            <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have already tried all the answers given Stackoverflow...But no use...

Please guys tell me where I am going wrong...Thanks!

Error Log:

```
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.myapp.myaction (has extras) } in com.AEM_n.SmsReceiver@405a07c8
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at com.AEM_n.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:37)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
04-07 02:34:02.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25593):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: The Intent class has a `putExtra()` method. No need for explicit `Bundle` construction. Also, `startActivity()` does not deliver the intent to broadcast receivers - it starts an activity.

Comment: how u broadcasting this broadcast means using `sendBroadcast` and `sendOrderedBroadcast` ?

Comment: why do you need a broadcasting ?? Your goal is to pass data between two activities? or what?

Comment: I just want to pass data (String) thats...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Following @Jason 's example...I did this...

In MainActivity or any activity from where you want to send intent from

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
intent.putExtra("extra", phoneNo); \\ phoneNo is the sent Number
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then in my SmsReceiver Class I did this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();

  Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

  if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
     String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");

  }
}
```

And in manifest.xml I added `"my.action.string"` though it was an option..

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <action android:name="my.action.string" />
        <!-- and some more actions if you want -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

worked like charm!!

Comment: I am working on a pretty similar conception that my app needs to handle. IN my case I have to pass the data through an  inter-device mechanism , which I have defined to be SMS, from one device to another. Is it possible to send the data as you did, by assigning to the intent the values? How to make my app the default app to treat when the sms is received?

Answer (score 4):

You starting an `Activity` instead of broadcasting `Intent`.
Try to change

```
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**UPDATE**:

You set no action and no component name to the `Intent`.
Try create intent as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("phN", phoneNo);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: In my receiving class, the `String receiveNumbers = intent.getStringExtras("phN";`

Comment: Did you check whether `getStringExtras` returns null or `intent` equals null?

Answer (score 0):

You would send a broadcast like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(action);
intent.putExtra("phN", phoneNo);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The `action` parameter is a `String` that correlates to the action you registered the `BroadcastReceiver` with. So if you registered your receiver like so:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter( "com.myapp.myaction" ) );
```

then `action` would be `"com.myapp.myaction"`

Comment: where do I register my BroadcastReceiver ? In my activity class?

Comment: Yes, typically in the `onCreate()` method. Be sure also to call `unregisterReceiver(receiver)` in the `onDestroy()` method (meaning you'll need to have a class reference to the receiver).

Comment: Please see my Manifest file...I tried your code...but application keep crashing.

Comment: post the stack trace for your crash please

Comment: I'm really confused on what you're trying to accomplish. Are you wanting to use the same `BroadcastReceiver` to receive SMS message and to receive broadcasted phone numbers? That's a bad idea. Your app is crashing because the SMS intent doesn't have a value with key "phN".

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do that...as I have to compare outgoing numbers with incoming numbers so that I could perform some action...I do not know any other way..PLease tell me one..for key I changed it "extra" on both places...

Comment: Will the object we send to BroadcastReceiver receiver persist? Even when the app closes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually very simple. It's enough that change onReceive() code just like it :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);

   if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
       String state = bundle.getString("phN");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, destinationActivity);
// Send String
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mNameEntryString);
// Send int
intent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

in receiver

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
// get string
String recievedString = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
// get int
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0); // 0 je default
```

Answer (score -3):

use sendbroadcast instead of startactivity.it will work..!!