# how to automatically refresh the chat on receiving gcm notification

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, chat

i am developing chat application. I want to automatically refresh the chat on receiving notification. I have tried using timer but its not that good as it refreshes after certain time period.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service and  Broadcast Receiver in your notification receiver class. When you received the notification, send the broadcast.  Add the data into your list and set it to the adapter.

Comment: can u send me the code..

Comment: @PrachiKarapurkar [How to pass data using broadcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032480/how-to-pass-data-to-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: OnReceiver u can add and set your adapter.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair you should not do any heavy task in broadcast receiver... better way is to start a service and do your work.

Comment: @sourabhbans you are right but according to her requirement i think broadcast receiver will be the best option. she only can add data to list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair agree with broadcast receiver.. but she need to store data to database also.. In that case she need to start service >> put the data in database(can be performed extra work there like network operations to download the data) >> use the `LocalBroadCastReceiver` to update activity/list...

Comment: @sourabhbans I agree with you on this point, and I think async task would be a good option too.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Nope... You shouldn't use background tasks with broadcast receivers. Broadcast receiver component is considered destroyed as soon as it returns from its onReceive() function. And if this was the only component in process, the process can get killed at any time.

Comment: Your process will be killed after onReceive method returns only if there is no other activity or service in your app is running.

If your broadcast receiver is an instance of an inner class and only receive when your activity is active, then your process will not be killed after onReceive method returns.

Comment: Oh yes, i got your point. She should use Service and  broadcast receiver.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair  correct :) ...

Comment: @sourabhbans I am editing my reply please vote up the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    String code = data.getString("code");

    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.e(TAG, "Message: " + message);


    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }


    Noty_bean noty = new Noty_bean();

    noty.setTitle("Title");
    noty.setMessage(message);
    noty.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    noty.setState(0);
    noty.setNoty_id("default id");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Your_refresh_service.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("noty",noty);
    intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
    startService(intent);

//    sendNotification(message);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

Comment: thanq but its not working..

Comment: notification data m saving in database n from local db m retrieving and setting to list how can i update the recycle view with new data

Comment: @PrachiKarapurkar You need to update the activity from your service.... check it..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739898/3790052

Comment: nd here ..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695943/3790052